# How can I track how much memory Linux is using?

Tags: linux, memory, cat

I am still learning Linux, I am using the `cat` command:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

for memory usage information but, there is no information appearing. Anybody had a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways aside of reading from `/proc/meminfo`.

The `free` command displays the amount of free and used memory in the system.

Using the flag `-h` makes `free` output in human readable format:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        1.0G        1.3G        4.3M        1.6G        2.6G
Swap:          5.8G        2.0M        5.8G
```

Be careful - depending on your language, the output might not line up this nicely. In that case, prefix the command with `LANG=C` to set the english language for this command only.

Comment: `watch free -h` will keep the output of free on screen and updating every 2s. This might be what was meant with 'track'

Answer (score 0):

For most non-technical uses, [`top(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) will do the job

```
top - 17:23:50 up 7 days, 19:15,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 172 total,   2 running, 170 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2049992 total,  1735420 used,   314572 free,   372420 buffers
KiB Swap:  2095100 total,      192 used,  2094908 free.   679116 cached Mem
```